# QPixmap copy contents of a square drawn into another image

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qpainter, qpixmap

I have an image onto which I draw a Rectangle as such. After that I am attempting to copy the contents of the rectangle onto another QLabel. This seems to work however i cannot seem to align the copied image starting from the left top corner of the image. Here is what I am doing

```
QPixmap original_image; 
original_image.load("c:\\Images\\myimg.jpg");
original_image = original_image.scaled(ui.label->size().width(),ui.label->size().height());

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Draw rectangle on this
QPixmap target_two(ui.label->size().width(),ui.label->size().height());
target_two.fill(Qt::transparent);     

QPixmap target(ui.label->size().width(),ui.label->size().height());
target.fill(Qt::transparent);    

QPainter painter(&target);
QPainter painter_two(&target_two);


QRegion r(QRect(0, 0, ui.label->size().width(), ui.label->size().height()), QRegion::RegionType::Rectangle);  //Region to start copying
painter.setClipRegion(r);
painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, original_image); //Draw the original image in the clipped region 


QRectF rectangle(x_start,y_start,clipRegion);
painter.drawRoundedRect(rectangle,0,0); //Last two parameters define the radius of the corners higher the radius more rounded it is

             QRegion r_two(rectangle.toRect(), QRegion::RegionType::Rectangle); 
             painter_two.setClipRegion(r_two);
             painter_two.drawPixmap(0,0,target); 


ui.label->setPixmap(target);    

ui.label_2->setPixmap(target_two);
```

The bottom picture is the image with the red rectangle in it and that is fine.
The top picture is a copy of the contents of the square.The only problem is its not starting from the top left corner.

Any suggestion on why I am not getting the copied content on the top left corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your logic is that both target and target_two images have the same sizes - size of the label, and you draw the copied image in the same position as it was in the initial label. So far so good. I would solve this by the following code:

```
[..]
// This both lines can be removed.
// QRegion r_two(rectangle.toRect(), QRegion::RegionType::Rectangle); 
// painter_two.setClipRegion(r_two);

// Target rect. in the left top corner.
QRectF targetRect(0, 0, rectangle.width(), rectangle.height());
QRectF sourceRect(rectangle);
// Draw only rectangular area of the source image into the new position.
painter_two.drawPixmap(targetRect, target, sourceRect);
[..]
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick perfectly could you explain what happens at  `painter_two.drawPixmap(targetRect, target, sourceRect);` and why we created a new `QRectF` sourceRect ?

Comment: @MistyD it draws the part of the source image into the target rectangular area. sourceRect created to make the code much understandable, but technically you can drop it and simply use 'rectangle'.